# How to replace "return optObj.isPresent() ? new Obj2(optObj) : null" in a functional style?

Tags: java, java-8, ide, option-type

My IDE (InteliJ) keeps pointing me that my code "Can be replaced with single expression in functional style", highlighting the `isPresent()`:

```
return timestamp.isPresent() ? new Obj2(timestamp.get()) : null;
```

`timestamp` is initialised like an Optional:

```
Optional<Date> timestamp = ...
```

My assumption is that I should use `ifPresent`. like this `timestamp.ifPresent(Obj2::new)`. But `ifPresent` is void and I have no opportunity to return the created Object. Also cant then return `null`. Is there a solution to my code?

Comment: Please get familiar with your IDE. Most IDEs don't only bother you with: "hey... you could fix this or simplify that", they often supply also quick fixes... you may also want to just search for "<your IDE name> apply quick fix" ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct in saying `ifPresent` returns void and hence not suitable in this case. Your IDE is suggesting that you can simply do:

```
timestamp.map(Obj2::new).orElse(null);
```

This reads as "if the Optional `timestamp` has a present state then pass the object it contains into the `Obj2` constructor and returns this new `Obj2` instance otherwise (`orElse`) return `null`.

---

on another note, IntelliJ IDEA can help you generate the code it's suggesting.

for example, given the below screenshot:

[image]

I simply clicked on the "highlighted" part and pressed "ALT + ENTER", and IntelliJ suggests whether it should replace the condition with a functional style.

Comment: This is correct, but I can’t help feeling like IntelliJ is idiotic for flagging it.  “Because you can” is not by itself a good reason to use Optional’s methods.

Comment: @VGR I definitely agree with you in the sense that "just because you can don't mean you have to" but I guess the good part of the suggestions is that it's "usually" the idiomatic way to do things. for example, given the example in the screenshot IDEA is suggesting it to be `person.orElse(null)` which in my eyes is much better.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, Like `forEach()`, `ifPresent()` takes Consumer as the parameter so it can introduce side effects. You would typically use it to print or log things.